# How to use a domain name for a different existing website

Tags: domains, web-hosting

I have a website, but I want to change the domain name to be used instead by another of my websites which is hosted somewhere else. How can I do that?

For example, I have www.example.com it is about cats. Now I have made a website about dogs, and it is hosted somewhere else. I want to use www.example.com for that dog website. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly the same process as setting up your first website. Change your nameservers to those of the new webhost's nameservers. It will take anywhere from minutes to hours for the DNS changes to propagate but eventually it will resolve to the new website.